# How can I add a new user story state in Rally?

Tags: rally

How can I add a new user story state in Rally?
i.e defined, complete, accepted, **custom state**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rally Knowledge Base article "Modifying Schedule States":
http://www.rallydev.com/help/modifying-schedule-states

Summary:

- Login to Rally as a Subscription or Workspace administrator

  Click on "Setup" (top right)

  Click on the "Workspaces & Projects" tab

  Find your Workspace in the list and click on it

  Click on "Work Products & Fields" (left column)

  In the "Work Product Type:" pull-down (near top left), select "User Story"

  In the list, find "*Schedule State*", click on the edit icon (far right)

  In the "Edit Field" pop-up, select "Custom (1)" in the "Drop Down List Values" box

  In the box beneath "Value" enter "Custom State" (or whatever name you want)

  Check the box under "Enabled"

  Click on the green checkmark icon ("Update Value" mouseover) to the right under "Actions"

  Click "Save & Close" (bottom of window)